# Spring Contants will ignore not all upper case field

Tags: java, spring

If a `class` have some `public static final` fields, 
then `spring Contants` class can help to provide help to these fields.

But for `lower case field name,` 
`Contants` not handle well. 
`Java` specification suggestion that 
we use all `upper case` for `public static final` fields name, 
but `lower case` name still valid.

see example:

```
public class Test {
    public static final int a = 1;
    public static final int B = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.springframework.core.Constants constants = new org.springframework.core.Constants(Test.class);
        System.out.println(constants.asNumber("b").intValue()); // line 1
        System.out.println(constants.asNumber("a").intValue()); // line 2
    }
}
```

`line 1` will output `2`, 
but `line 2` will `throw ConstantException: Field 'A' not found in class Test`

> Why does not they compare them case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of **convention**, compile time constants in Java are **always** is `UPPER_UNDERSCORE`. No exceptions.

From the [documentation for `Constants`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Constants.html)

> Consider class `Foo` containing `public final static int CONSTANT1 = 66;` An instance of this class wrapping `Foo.class` will return the constant value of `66` from its `asNumber` method given the argument "CONSTANT1".

So while a name in `camelCase` or (heaven forbid) `lower_underscore` is *valid* according to the Java programming language; is it against accepted convention and not to be encouraged.

Comment: But I still think Constant just compare with the String user input, no need to change them to upper case. then line 1 throw exception Field 'b' not found in class Test